# Generator of C code for Bluez

Tags: arm, bluez, codegen, gdbus

I'm about to develop my program bluetooth in C on ARM platform, which is supposed to be able to exchange information with bluez via dbus interface. 
I have succeeded in cross-compiling the Bluez, but the part of "client" in C is always a big work for me. 
Fortrunately several month ago, I have seen a piece of code that offered a quite similar solution of this kind, on the head of which there mentionned "Generated by gdbus-codegen. DO NOT EDIT." 
So from this information I can be 99% sure that this kind of code is open. But I know quite few about this generator, and I managed to search for more information about it but I have found very few things after a lot of dig work thoughout all the websites for several weeks/months. The only thing I know is that might be "gdbus-codegen" who translate some "xml" file into "C" program. 
But where can I get this xml? Can anybody give me some information about it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please say specifically what it is about the [official documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-codegen.html) that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

xml file lists the method call and signals provided by the service.
This is developed by server side application.

**gdbus-codegen** is used to generate .c and .h files from the xml file. The generated .c and .h files provide high level DBus API calls. This is used by the client/server for method calls and signal processing.

[gdbus-codegen usage](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gio/ch30s05.html#gdbus-example-gdbus-codegen)